Помогите решить задачку на python для олимпиады
Задача D. Новогодние эксперименты
Ограничение по времени: 2 секунды
Руслан подарил своему другу хомяку Артему на Новый год массив a. Артем очень обрадовался
подарку и решил провести над ним эксперименты.
Всего существует 5 типов операций:
• AND — операция: для всех элементов массива a применяется побитовое И с числом c. То есть,
каждый элемент ai заменяется на ai AND c.
• OR — операция: для всех элементов массива a применяется побитовое ИЛИ с числом c. То
есть, каждый элемент ai заменяется на ai OR c.
• XOR — операция: для всех элементов массива a применяется побитовое исключающее ИЛИ
с числом c. То есть, каждый элемент ai заменяется на ai XOR c.
• Запрос на значение i-го элемента массива.
• Запрос на значение k-го по величине элемента массива.
Формат входных данных
Каждый тест состоит из нескольких наборов входных данных. Первая строка содержит одно
целое число t (1 <= t <= 10^5
) — количество наборов входных данных. Далее следует описание наборов
входных данных.
Первая строка содержит целое число n (1 <= n <= 2 · 10^5
) — количество элементов в массиве a.
Вторая строка содержит n целых чисел ai (0 <= ai < 2^30) — элементы массива a.
Третья строка содержит целое число q (1 <= q <= 2 · 10^5
) — количество запросов.
Следующие q строк содержат запросы в формате x c, где x — тип операции (от 1 до 5), а c —
целое число, для операций 1–3 ограничение 0 <= c < 2
30, а для операций 4–5 ограничение 1 <= i, k <= n.
Описание операций:
1 c : применить операцию AND к каждому элементу массива a.
2 c : применить операцию OR к каждому элементу массива a.
3 c : применить операцию XOR к каждому элементу массива a.
4 i : вывести значение i-го элемента массива (индексация с 1).
5 k : вывести значение k-го по величине элемента массива (1-й по величине — наименьший элемент).
Гарантруется, что сумма всех n и q не более 4 · 10^5
.
Формат выходных данных
Для каждого запроса типа 4 i или 5 k выведите соответствующее значение на отдельной строке:
• Для запроса типа 4 i выведите значение i-го элемента массива (индексация с 1).
• Для запроса типа 5 k выведите значение k-го по величине элемента массива (1-й по величине —
наименьший элемент).
Пример
стандартный ввод стандартный вывод
1
3
1 2 3
3
3 1
4 2
5 1
Выходные:
3
0

Во-первых, нужно показать свое решение, путь даже неоптимальное. Во-вторых, это невозможно читать, какое-то форматирование требуется.
